DWH Model - Relationship between Fact tables
I have been given a new requirement which in Power BI would probably be fixed in Power Query so each data set might not have an issue with multiple fact tables but with how I store the data I am unsure if I should combine some of the data in my facts so then I don't have a need to join a fact with a fact.
My fact is the occupancy/contract, this has the FK to customer and also to asset (which is another fact table), I have also just had to look at household so this is the customers living in a property, but they are not on the contract so will not show in the occupancy, but I can find the occupancy they are associated with and then identify the customer record from the dimension.
These relationships:

fact.asset has a one-to-many relationship with fact.Occupancy (occupancies end so only ever 1 active occupancy but the same asset over time will have several occupancies)
fact.occupancy has a one-to-many relationship with fact.household, both of which link to dimension customer seperately
fact.occupancy one-to-many relationship with dim.cusomter
fact.household one-to-manyrelationship with dim.cusomter

I thought about merging fact.occupancy and fact.household but this would probably cause me more problems with kpis around occupancies, so I am sure how to model this.
It could be this is just something I handle in Power BI since each requirement will be different, but I also worry as the model grows, I could be creating a lot of issues and requirements keep changing.
I think that maybe my fact tables should all form 1 fact as occupant/household and the asset and customer are dimensions.


Your model has lots of problems... In a proper star schema, you should only have 1:M relations between dimensions and fact tables. Relations between fact tables should never be allowed, as well as relations between dimensions. 1:1 relations usually indicate a modeling mistake, they should be avoided.

I agree, originally, I started with a single fact and dims but then additional facts came into scope because each dept has different requirements.
I have also updated my question, occupancies has a one to many not one to one. My dimensions do not have 1:1 relationship.
I am thinking I need to remodel completely, make a factless fact and then move to a snowflake schema
